# Getting a warning message after opening email using PHP

Tags: php, email, smtp, gmail, phpmailer

I am using PHPMailer for sending an email. Emails are getting proper but whenever I am opening email which I was sent using PHP Mailer I am getting a warning message.

**Note**: If I remove anchor tag from $phpMailerText then I am not getting any warning.If I add anchor tag then I am getting warning.Would you help me in this?

[image]

```
require 'mail/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $to = $email;
    //Create a new PHPMailer instance
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    //Enable SMTP debugging
    // 0 = off (for production use)
    // 1 = client messages
    // 2 = client and server messages
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;

    //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    // Headers 
$headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n"
              . "X-mailer: smtp.gmail.com" . "\r\n" // this will identify the real sender
              . "Precedence: bulk" . "\r\n" // this will say it is bulk sender
              .  "List-Unsubscribe:abc@gmail.com\r\n" // this will reveal the OPT-OUT address
                . "Reply-To: $to\n"
                . "To: $to\n"
                . "From: $to\n";

    //Set the hostname of the mail server
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

    //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
    $mail->Port = 587;

    //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

    //Whether to use SMTP authentication
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

    //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
    $mail->Username = "abc@gmail.com";

    //Password to use for SMTP authentication
    $mail->Password = "****";

    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    $mail->setFrom('abc@gmail.com', 'code');

    //Set an alternative reply-to address
    $mail->addReplyTo('abc@gmail.com', 'code');

    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress($to, 'Customer');

    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = 'code';

    $phpMailerText="<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <a href='http://www.companyname.com/changepassword.php?user_id=" .$User_id1."'>Create your password here</a>
    </body>
    </html>";

    $mail->msgHTML($phpMailerText);

    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = ' ';

    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) { echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {  
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what component gives you that warning, most likely some email client or web application that you use to _read_ the email? If so then most likely it is rated as SPAM email. That is what you have to check. Open the received emails source code and check if you have headers injected by the spam detection engine. Those typically give hints on _what details_ exactly lead to the rating. That is a good starting point to modify your message. Often it is not only the content itself, but the way _how_ the message is sent and structured.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.arkascha, I am new in this and I don't have any idea about this.

Comment: Sure, that is why I gave you some starting point. To _really_ open an email you typically need a _real_ email client, not just some web frontend. A good email client offers an option like "View message source" or similar. That is what you want.

Comment: As @arkascha rightly pointed out, this is a client based issue. The issue is down to having an achor inside your email. This security method is to ensure that the user fully trusts the source before opening the link. The answer below will not bypass these checks if enforced by client.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code and do the other steps.

1. Create reverse dns record
2. Configure SPF records

> ```
> $to = $email;
> //Create a new PHPMailer instance
> $mail = new PHPMailer;
>
> //Enable SMTP debugging
> // 0 = off (for production use)
> // 1 = client messages
> // 2 = client and server messages
> $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
>
> //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
> $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
>
> // Headers 
> $headers = "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\n"
>               . "X-mailer: YOUR_SITE_DOMAIN Server" . "\r\n" // this will identify the real sender
>               . "Precedence: bulk" . "\r\n" // this will say it is bulk sender
>               .  "List-Unsubscribe:info@YOUR_SITE_DOMAIN\r\n" // this will reveal the OPT-OUT address
>                 . "Reply-To: $email\n"
>                 . "To: $email\n"
>                 . "From: $email\n";
>
> $mail->addCustomHeader( $headers );
>
> //Set the hostname of the mail server
> $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
>
> //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
> $mail->Port = 587;
>
> //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
> $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
>
> //Whether to use SMTP authentication
> $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
>
> //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
> $mail->Username = "me@companydomain.com";
>
> //Password to use for SMTP authentication
> $mail->Password = "****";
>
> // Because html is being used
> $mail->isHTML(true);
>
> //Set who the message is to be sent from
> $mail->setFrom('me@companydomain.com', 'code');
>
> //Set an alternative reply-to address
> $mail->addReplyTo('me@companydomain.com', 'code');
>
> //Set who the message is to be sent to
> $mail->addAddress($to, 'Customer');
>
> //Set the subject line
> $mail->Subject = 'code';
>
> $phpMailerText="<!DOCTYPE HTML><html>
> <head>
> <title>HTML email</title>
> </head>
> <body>
>
> <a href='http://www.companyname.com/changepassword.php?user_id=" .$User_id1."'>Create your password here</a>
> </body>
> </html>";
>
> $mail->msgHTML($phpMailerText);
>
> //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
> $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; 
>
> //send the message, check for errors
> if (!$mail->send()) { echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
> } else {  
> }
> ```

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Dean, but still i am getting same issue

Comment: Mr.Dean, I am getting error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in $headers

Comment: I am not getting any warning message in Outlook but getting  in Gmail

Comment: Ok. I added 2 instated of 0.

Comment: Did you also create the DNS and SPF records.

Comment: I am using Gmail id now. so is it monetary to create? If yes the please assist me where should I go and create it?

Comment: Or Do you have any PHP code to send email without getting any warning message?

Answer (score 0):

Please use following code and tell me what happends.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for Gmail
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "email@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "password";
$mail->SetFrom("email@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("email@gmail.com");

 if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 } else {
    echo "Message has been sent";
 }
```

Comment: Mr.Dean, email@gmail.com and example@gmail.com both email will be same right?

Comment: I am getting error, 2017-01-04 10:47:39 SMTP NOTICE: EOF caught while checking if connected 2017-01-04 10:47:39 SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

Comment: Yes they will be the same

Comment: Above error, I disable the IsSMTP and error goes.I am getting email  in spam if i send Gmail to Gmail but if send email from Gmail to my company email id which is config on outlook there i am getting emails inbox.